# How do I have my program terminate with an error if a valid integer isn't entered?

Tags: java, dialog

For school, I am making a program where the user enters three integers and the program finds the product of these three integers and outputs the result to the user. The teacher requires that I use the JOptionPane class. How do I make the program terminate with an error when a non valid integer is entered. And also, how do I output the answer in a java window? Thanks in advance!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ASTheProductofThreeGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //initializes variable "answer" of type integer

        //prompts the user to enter their first integer for the product of three
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your first"
                + " value as an integer")); 

        //prompts the user to enter their second integer
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your second"
                + " value as an integer")); 

        //prompts the user to enter their third integer
        int value3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your third"
                + " value as an integer")); 

        int answer = value1 * value2 * value3;
```

Answer (score 0):

An exception will be thrown by Integer.parseInt if the string is not a valid Integer.  You should handle the NumberFormatException and then call System.exit.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ASTheProductofThreeGUI {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //initializes variable "answer" of type integer

    //prompts the user to enter their first integer for the product of three
try {
    int value1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your first"
            + " value as an integer")); 

    //prompts the user to enter their second integer
    int value2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your second"
            + " value as an integer")); 

    //prompts the user to enter their third integer
    int value3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your third"
            + " value as an integer")); 
 catch (NumberFormatException e){
    e.printStackTrace("Invalid Integer entered.");
    System.exit(0);
 }
    int answer = value1 * value2 * value3;
```

Also asking homework assignments as a question is frowned upon so I will leave your second question for you to find out.

Answer (score 0):

smokeyrobot, let me expand your proposal and give Samuel a hint on clean coding. As Robert C. Martin tells in his excelent book 'Clean Code', try/catch blocks are ugly and confuse the structure of the code mixing error processing with normal processing. Following this, here is my proposal for Samuel's problem:

```
public class JOptionPaneExample {

public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        productOfThreeNumbers();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showErrorDialog();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

private static void productOfThreeNumbers() {
    //initializes variable "answer" of type integer

    //prompts the user to enter their first integer for the product of three
    int value1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your first"
            + " value as an integer"));

    //prompts the user to enter their second integer
    int value2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your second"
            + " value as an integer"));

    //prompts the user to enter their third integer
    int value3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your third"
            + " value as an integer"));

    int answer = value1 * value2 * value3;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%d * %d * %d = %d", value1, value2, value3, answer));
}

private static void showErrorDialog() {
    //Put here code to show a friendly error message...
}}
```